# How to execute a procedure inside a package

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to manually  call the procedure **PROC_ENTRY_TIME** for loading fresh data into **TABLE_ENTRY_TIME**. How do I do that?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PK_ENTRY_TIME IS
PROCEDURE PROC_ENTRY_TIME
AS
BEGIN
    execute immediate 'truncate table TABLE_ENTRY_TIME';
    insert into TABLE_ENTRY_TIME 
        SELECT  TABLE_CASE.ID_NUMBER , max( TABLE_ACT_ENTRY.ENTRY_TIME )
        FROM  SA.TABLE_CASE TABLE_CASE 
            INNER JOIN  SA.TABLE_ACT_ENTRY   TABLE_ACT_ENTRY
            ON  TABLE_CASE.OBJID = TABLE_ACT_ENTRY.ACT_ENTRY2CASE
     commit;
END  PROC_ENTRY_TIME;
```

Comment: `exec pk_entry_time.proc_entry_time`

Comment: it gives invalid sql statement error.Does not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "it gives invalid sql statement error.Does not work! "

Well, your posted code is invalid so it won't compile. You've got a missing semi-colon, and you need a GROUP BY clause for the aggregation criteria. What happens if you fix it like this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PK_ENTRY_TIME IS

    PROCEDURE PROC_ENTRY_TIME
    AS
    BEGIN
        execute immediate 'truncate table TABLE_ENTRY_TIME';
        insert into TABLE_ENTRY_TIME 
            SELECT  TABLE_CASE.ID_NUMBER , max( TABLE_ACT_ENTRY.ENTRY_TIME )
            FROM  SA.TABLE_CASE TABLE_CASE 
                INNER JOIN  SA.TABLE_ACT_ENTRY   TABLE_ACT_ENTRY
                ON  TABLE_CASE.OBJID = TABLE_ACT_ENTRY.ACT_ENTRY2CASE
                group by table_case.id_number;
         commit;
    END  PROC_ENTRY_TIME;
END  PK_ENTRY_TIME;
```

As for running it, it depends on what client you're using. Here is how to run an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
begin
    pk_entry_time.proc_entry_time;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sithara, you have a missing semicolon after your insert, I have edited the code,try it. Later follow what @a_horse_with_no_name has suggested above i.e.

```
exec pk_entry_time.proc_entry_time
```

Note: not sure how you debugged but putting it in any editor would have given you the clue about the problem.